# Alter PostgreSQL column from integer to decimal

Tags: postgresql

Thanks to a last minute client request a integer field in our database now needs to be a decimal, to two points.A value of `23` should become `23.00`.

Is there a nice way I can convert the table and cast the data across?

I'll freely admit, I haven't done anything like this with PostgreSQL before so please be gentle with me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
alter table t alter column c type decimal(10,2);
```

**Edit:**

As @Oli stated in the comments; the first number is the entire length of the number (excluding the point) so the maxval for `(10,2)` would be `99999999.99`

Comment: What does the `(10,2)` represent? Does it mean it'll accept a value up to `9999999999.99`?

Comment: I see now that the first number is the entire length of the number (excluding the point) so the maxval for `(10,2)` would be `99999999.99`

Answer (score 0):

`alter table table_name alter column columname type decimal(16,2);`

> for converting data type from int to decimal. with precession after decimal point 2 values it will come for example 10.285 then it will be 10.23.or in decimal place we can use numeric also it will work.